# Draw a smoother line and figure out the sharp changes(slope) point from a time series data where value will be in between 0 to 100

Tags: python, regression, data-visualization, data-analysis, spline

I have scattered time series data where x is date-time and y is the value ranging from 0 to 100. I want to draw a smoother line which will be best fit for given data. I also want to get the points where there is a substantial changes occurs.

You can find the sample data-set [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sDBDElVhvSWe-cXF_VmrEfCKI6KpLcHwRbpvK98NM9A/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Distorted graph]

**Note,** There might be some null value of y for given x. I will appreciate any example using python.

Comment: It does not seem that there is a correlation between data. So drawing smoother lines will not serve to a purpose other than a good-looking graph. I think vertical bars as graph style would give a better view than smooth lines.

Comment: @gokaysatir I need to draw line, data point will be huge so showing them in vertical bars will not be a good idea. Besides, If I get the sharp slope points I can figure out if there is any anomaly or not since for my case changes will be gradual. So I think I am clear about my requirement.